# Map some return codes to zero (success) in bash

Tags: bash

I have a shell script that returns a bunch of different error codes. Some are innocuous and I want to treat them as success, and then use `&&` to run another command (I.e. all in the same list command). Is there a way to do this?

For example:

`cmd1 && cmd2;`

cmd1 returns 0 on success, 1 on the innocuous error, and 2 on the real error. I want the command to keep executing on 0 or 1.

Comment: Can you show us some code please?

Comment: Sure, added example code just now. Thx.

Comment: You'd need to execute `cmd1`, then execute `cmd2` __if__ the return code is 0 or 1.  To elaborate, there is probably no short-cut here to be able to use short-circuiting.

Comment: @devnull Oh I was thinking maybe there was some kind of filter/mask operator I did not know about.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in this way

```
cmd1; (( $? < 2 )) && cmd2
```

Comment: Yeah I knew that. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `&&` to continue on `0` return code.

However, you can read the return code and make a less strict decision based on it (using either `if` or even `&&`):

```
/your/command; rc=$?
[ $rc -lt 2 ] && /your/continuation
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `test`

```
cmd1; test $? -lt 2 && cmd2
```